# Is it possible to Mock Specflow's ScenarioContext? (C#)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, specflow

Trying to write a unit test for a Specflow step which uses the ScenarioContext. This step is trying to retrieve a property's value from the ScenarioContext. Is it possible to Mock the ScenarioContext so I can set a value for this property?

Using VS professional and Moq framework on my local. Thanks

As far as I could check the ScenarioContext is not implementing any interface. Trying Mock on ScenarioContext failed (reason in the code block below)

```
private Mock<IPropertyBucket> _propertyBucket;

ctor(){

    var mo = new Mock<ScenarioContext>(); // this line fails as ScenarioContext has no public contructor.
    mo.Object.Add("response", Response);  // this property is what the specflow step is using eventually

    _propertyBucket = new Mock<IPropertyBucket>();
    _propertyBucket.Setup(pb => pb.ScenarioContext).Returns(mo.Object);  
}
```

FYI: I am working on a multi-framework target solution. This framework works for both net472 and netCore3.1.x. The implementation of ScenarioContext is different between both .Net Core and .Net framework.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What does Intellisense tell you about the ScenarioContext type?

Comment: Hi @GregBurghardt, I updated the question with what I tried so far. thanks

Comment: ScenarioContext inherits from Dictionary<string, object>, which implements IDictionary<string, object>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting pseudo code of what I ended up adopting, it has served me well for the past year didn't have to make any changes.

Basically a wrapper was created around ScenarioContext which has a private instance of ScenarioContext (MyScenarioContext in the following code), now only the required methods were exposed. Needless to say, the wrapper had an interface tied to it which did allow mocking ScenarioContext all together.

```
public class ScenarioContext : IScenarioContext
{
    public ScenarioContext(TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {            
        MyScenarioContext = scenarioContext;
    }

    private TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioContext MyScenarioContext { get; }

    public IObjectContainer ScenarioContainer => MyScenarioContext.ScenarioContainer;

    public StepInfo StepInfo => MyScenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo;

    ScenarioInfo IScenarioContext.ScenarioInfo => MyScenarioContext.ScenarioInfo;

    public bool Clear(string propertyName)
    {
        if (!MyScenarioContext.ContainsKey(propertyName)) return false;
        MyScenarioContext.Remove(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public T GetProperty<T>(string key)
    {
        if (MyScenarioContext.ContainsKey(key))
            return (T)MyScenarioContext[key];
        throw new Exception($"No key remembered with the name {key}");
    }
    //.
    //.
    //.
    // Other useful functions such as Remember etc.
}
```